# Saving monthly income from query (Firestore) in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to implement a code that will add to a variable the total service cost from each day separately. I am able to get the currentDay total income, but when a day is passed i lost his total income and the variable is updated to the new day income.

Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1; //Later be used here

    firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("confirmed-appointments")
    .doc(currentMonth.toString()) //Query only through the currentMonth!!
    .collection(checkDayNumber(day).toString()) //Calling a function that checks which day it is and querying accordingly.
    .get().then(querySnapshot => {
      let serviceCostTotal = 0; //Will hold currentMonth Total Income.
      let arrays = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        serviceCostTotal = serviceCostTotal + parseInt(doc.data().serviceCost,10) //Calculate Total Month income using this formula
      }) 
      setIncomeHold(serviceCostTotal);
      console.log("ServiceCost Total => ", serviceCostTotal); //1200
      let incomeArrays = [...arrays, incomeHold];
      console.log("IncomeArrays: " , incomeArrays);
    }) // then ends
  }, [])
```

Firebase path:

```
/users/5x7bF6YEYpffHy1JGAcblHNyHiF2/confirmed-appointments/10/11/nKHnLTuJvkpG5VfJUwSu
```

10 - Month
11 - Day (11, October)

for better example: right now the date is October, 11 and the total income is 1200$
tommorow the query will calculate the October , 12 income that will be X$ and the October, 11 will gone.

what i want to do is to calculate the total month income, if today i made 1200$ and yesterday i made 3000$ , the income will be 4200$

Later on i would like to create an array that will hold every month of the year income, array[0] will hold January income and follows....

Comment: Can you please post the setIncomeHold function?

Comment: Why not save the data from each day to firestore, then create a fucntion that reads all the saved values from  firestore and sums all of the entries? I'm not understanding why you are loosing the information after each day passes.